# jQuery Tablesorter error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'count' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I'm using the jQuery Tablesorter plugin to sort a table based on the selected value of a select box located above the table. On document ready, I initialize the table to have it initially sorted on the 4th column with the other headers set to be non-sortable, which is working fine. When I try to resort the table based on the selected option, it throws an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'count' of undefined

Any ideas on how to get the selected option to resort the table?

Select element:

```
<select name="table-sort" class="table-sort">
  <option value="value1">Sort by name</option>
  <option value="value2">Sort by amount</option>
</select>
```

Javascript file:

```
  $( ".table-sort" ).on("change", function(){
    switch ($(this).val()) {
      case 'value1':
        var sorting = [[0,0]];
        $(".my-table").trigger("sorton", [sorting]);
        return false;
        break;
      case 'value2':
        var sorting = [[1,0]];
        $(".my-table").trigger("sorton",[sorting]);
        return false;
        break;     
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked for me. I did modify it a little ([tablesorter v2.0.5b demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/1157/)):

HTML

```
<!-- value contains zero-based column index -->
<select name="table-sort" class="table-sort">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">Sort by last name</option>
    <option value="3">Sort by total</option>
</select>
```

Script

```
$(".table-sort").on("change", function () {
    var column = $(this).val();
    $(".my-table").trigger("sorton", [ [[ column, 0 ]] ]);
    return false;
});
```

As for the error, tablesorter does store a `count` value in the header element to help keep track of the sort direction, but I'm not seeing the error in that demo. Maybe something else is interfering? What does your HTML in the `thead` look like?